# /path/to/your/fftw

Tags: cmake

I am new to ubuntu. I just installed fftw in my home terminal. I have to link it's path to cmake . How can I retrieve path to my fftw library? i tried `locate fftw3-dev`. And secondly while linking cmake to a program. I am getting error:

```sh
 ‘HWLOC_TOPOLOGY_FLAG_IO_DEVICES’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘HWLOC_TOPOLOGY_FLAG_IS_THISSYSTEM’?
507 | hwloc_topology_set_flags(topo, HWLOC_TOPOLOGY_FLAG_IO_DEVICES);
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| HWLOC_TOPOLOGY_FLAG_IS_THISSYSTEM
make[2]: *** [src/gromacs/CMakeFiles/libgromacs.dir/build.make:10782: src/gromacs/CMakeFiles/libgromacs.dir/hardware/hardwaretopology.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3636: src/gromacs/CMakeFiles/libgromacs.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

getting error
What am I doing wrong here.
My commands were

```
cmake … -DGMX_BUILD_OWN_FFTW=OFF -DREGRESSIONTEST_DOWNLOAD=ON -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH= /usr/share/doc/libfftw3-dev -DGMX_HWLOC=ON -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc
sudo make
```

Comment: At first change `…` to `..` (normal plain two dots). Then add output of `dpkg -l | grep fftw` to the question.

Comment: You may need an HWE kernel, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack